# TensorflowJS and Tensorflow_datasets

Tags: javascript, tensorflow, tensorflow.js

How can we import tensorflow_datasets in tensorflowJS. The only example to import TensorFlow dataset shown on the website uses python

Comment: If the answer solves your issue don't forget to accept that answer and close the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [tfjs-data](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@tensorflow/tfjs-data) for importing datasets but as it is provided in the repo it is not yet production-ready.

```
import * as tf from '@tensorflow/tfjs';
URL = ""
const dataset = tf.data.csv(
   URL, {
      columnConfigs: {
         medv: {
         isLabel: true
      }
   }
});
```

So you have to use this package or you can process the data from your model and move it to some other resource and access it from there.